# Drupal Image cache issue

Tags: image, drupal-6

I am using Drupal6 and image cache was working fine earlier...but last few days its not working and it throwing error "The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors."  Earlier i have this issue and i solved it my removing some white space before the

For example, if i have image URL, like this, `http://localhost/drupal/sites/defaults/files/imagecache/profile_85/pictures/vinodkumar_8542.jpg`

its showing correctly in the browser, but the same image is not working when i use path like this

```
http://localhost/drupal/index.php?q=sites/defaults/files/imagecache/profile_85/pictures/vinodkumar_8542.jpg
```

Please help me in solving this big issue...

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me because i did a custom module with a different encoding i found my module contains "i<< j" before "php tags" that made my image corrupted as it added this encoding at the header of the image .. Check your files . you can try to install image captcha to see if the drupal can generate image or not if not then you can try my solution as it worked for me after a hell of times.
you can check this sites :

http://drupal.org/node/1843304

http://drupal.org/node/1302076

http://drupal.org/project/issues/imagecache?status=All&categories=All "check open issues"

Comment: I did what you said...but still having the same issue...but what you given is very useful to me...thanks george